# iterate through sub-objects of ng-repeat with dynamic key value pair

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a JSON object and I am iterating through this.

But, each iterated object has some child objects where I do need to iterate through them as well.

JSON structure:

```
[{
    'name': 'a',
    't1':'v1',
    't2':'v2',
    't3': {
        'c1':'cv1',
        'c2':'cv2',
         ...
    }
}, {
    ...
}]
```

This JSON object has (key, value) pair and value can have its children with (key, value) pair again.

I wanted to create labels for each key value pair and for child key value pair also.

Comment: Print here the output you are expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about how your exact html structure looks like.Please consider writing a good question clearing these aspects.(question should have your input data,expected output data,what you have tried and what errors you are getting).

However I think you need to set up something like this where json is the data structure inputted and I am looping inner children objects and printing them.

```
<div ng-repeat="parent in json">
      {{parent.name}} - {{parent.t1}} - {{parent.t2}}
      <b>Childrens:</b><br/> 
       <ul>
         <li ng-repeat="child in parent.t3"> 
           {{child.c1}} 
           ...

         </li>
       </ul>
</div>
```

### Edit (in case of dynamic key value)

if your key value pairs are not known the I would advise to do this -

```
<div ng-repeat="parent in json">   
    <div ng-repeat="(parentkey, parentvalue) in parent">
        {{parentkey}} : {{parentvalue}}
        <b>Childrens :</b></br>
        <li ng-repeat="(k, v) in parentkey"> 
               {{k}} : {{v}} 
               ...

        </li>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, as you mentioned I have same scenario, just the difference is I don't know t3 key. Means the Key and values(Property and values) of children are dynamic. I don't know what is key, so I can not use t3 in <li ng-repeat> tag. What can I do for that? I can not write parent.t3 and child.c1(dont know keys t3 and c1).